# How to re-scale D3 map after zooming

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a D3 map that I have created on a codepen. Below is the link

http://codepen.io/redixhumayun/full/VPepqM/

I have included some basic zooming and panning onto it. However, when I zoom I want the dots to re-scale to account for the zoom, not just stay the same size. I want them to separate out over the greater area that will be provided after zooming in.

I'm not sure what exactly I should be looking for, which is why I am having a hard time finding it.

Here is the code for the zoom I have currently implemented

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
             .on('zoom', zoomed);

svg.call(zoom);

//defining the zoomed function here
function zoomed() {
  map.attr('transform', d3.event.transform)
  meteorite.attr('transform', d3.event.transform);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the circles representing the meteorites to stay at their **original** size, regardless the zoom, this is a possible solution:

Rename your circles' variable:

```
var meteorites = meteorite.selectAll('circle')
    //etc..
```

And set their radii and stroke according to the zoom:

```
meteorites.attr('r', function(d) {
        return weight_scale(d.properties.mass) / d3.event.transform.k
    })
    .attr("stroke-width", 1 / d3.event.transform.k);
```

Here is the CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPapPa?editors=1010

PS: because of scope issues, I had to move some functions.

Comment: Hey, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Good to know. I was confused because you said that you didn't want them to *"stay the same size"*... In fact, that was what you wanted!

Comment: I was wondering if you could explain exactly what d3.event.transform.k is doing here though?

Comment: It's the zoom (or scale) factor: https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#zoom-transforms